# EasyMotion get text in commandline

Tags: vim

I would like to add an `EasyMotion` mapping, such that `*` maps to `<CR>` if there is already one character, but `*` is itself when zero. For example, something like this:

```
EMCommandLineNoreMap * <CR>         <-- if one character entered
EMCommandLineNoreMap * *           <-- if zero characters entered
```

I know I can use an `<expr>` for this, but I'm not sure how to check to see the output of the current command, for example:

[image]

I'm hoping to be able to do something like this, but not sure how/if it's possible:

```
EMCommandLineNoreMap <expr> * (egetcmdline() != '') ? '<CR>' : '*'
```

How could that be done?

Comment: I am fairly certain this is not possible